# In Numpy, how to enforce a view to an array remain as a view?

Tags: python, numpy

I created a view (`x1`) to a slice of a NumPy array.

```
x = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
x1 = x[0,:]
```

If I apply `+=` operator, for example, it modifies the data of the original array `x` (`x1` is the same view to `x`)

```
x1 += 10
```

However, if I apply something more complicated:

```
x1 = x1**2 + 10
```

A new array is assigned to `x1` and `x1` is no longer a view to `x`, which is not what I want.

I am wondering if there's a Pythonic way to enforce to `x1` remain as a view?

Comment: `x1 += ...` is an in-place operation (to the extent that `x1` allows it).  `x1 = ...` assigns a new value to `x1`.  This is basic Python behavior.  `x1` remains a view only if it is modified in-place.  You may need to review the distinction between a "variable" and the object, or value, assigned to it.

Answer (score 3):

In these cases, you should use the `arr[:]` syntax.
In this way, you refer to the x1 value. It can be considered as a pointer (kind of).

```
x1[:] = x1**2 + 10

x1
> array([10, 11, 14, 19])

x
> array([[10, 11, 14, 19],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```